# Is there any sample working code for creating S3's pre-signed URLs in Kotlin

Tags: amazon-s3, kotlin

Is there any sample working code for creating S3's pre-signed URLs in Kotlin? Can I adapt it from a Java example?

Comment: In IntelliJ you can just paste a Java snippet into a Kotlin file and IntelliJ will convert it to Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct copy (converted by IntelliJ) of the sample code [on this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html).

```
val s3client = AmazonS3Client(ProfileCredentialsProvider())

val expiration = java.util.Date()
var msec = expiration.time
msec += (1000 * 60 * 60).toLong() // 1 hour.
expiration.time = msec

val generatePresignedUrlRequest = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey)
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET) // Default.
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration)

val s = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest)
```

Here is the same code which is a bit more idiomatic Kotlin and using Java 8 LocalDateTime for expiration date calculation:

```
val expiration = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(1)
val generatePresignedUrlRequest = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey).apply {
  method = HttpMethod.GET
  expiration = Date.from(expiration.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())
}
val s3client = AmazonS3Client(ProfileCredentialsProvider())
val s = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest)
```